# Android displaying linear layout in center to textview

Tags: android

Iam having a custom list view where in a row i have 3 text views and 3 images each below each textview

```
          (Relative Layout)
              TextView1              Textiew2           TextView3
opening---->(LinearLayout1)       (LinearLayout2)     (LinearLayout3)
              ImageView1             ImageView2          ImageView3
closing---->(/LinearLayout1)      (/LinearLayout2)    (/LinearLayout3)
closing-->(/RelativeLayout)
```

Now the output comes like the imageview is not center totextview, i mean if you have your text and image in center and its centerhorizontal then how it looks like, i need same on right and left end too, text and image in right end should be centered in right side , and same for left also. Please suggest me what to do.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="47dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/book1" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In this above xml my textview is leftaligned and its text inside is centered, Now iam having one image below it which i want to align center of the above textview  not parents center

Comment: what is the problem you have faced while develop this?

Comment: please paste code here

Comment: your query is not clear?

Comment: Please Post related xml code

Comment: Post your xml, a screenshot of what it looks like now, and if possible a drawing or explanation of what's off and what you really want

Comment: your question is not clear, post the xml code you did, what is you requirement?

Comment: Iam not having enough reputation to share screenshot. above i have edited my post. 
In that above xml my textview is leftaligned and its text inside is centered, Now iam having one image below it which i want to align center of the above textview  not parents center

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.33">

 <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Your title"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.33">

 <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Your title"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>


   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.34">

 <TextView
          android:id="@+id/textView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Your title"
          android:textStyle="bold" />

  <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/btn"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try That:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/book1" />
</LinearLayout>
```